# Put String result from Encode Base64 to JSONObject Out Of Memory

Tags: android, json, base64, out-of-memory

I read many question about `OOM` but I am still stuck. I can not use `jsonObject.toString` to get array `bytes` at all. I have an Image taken by Camera and I want to send it into a service. I send it with HTTP POST with format :

```
{
 request : {
            image : encodedImageWithBase64
           }
}
```

But I can't make a JSONObject cause `OOM`. Here String example from result Encoded Image : https://pastebin.com/RUXae9VU

Here my snippet code :

```
JSONObject requestDict = new JSONObject();
            try {
                JSONArray tempRequestDic = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("imagedata", strEncode64);
                tempRequestDic.put(obj);

                obj.put("image", tempRequestDic);
                requestDict.put("request", obj); /* Here I get the Exception*/

//                    String strReqDict = String.valueOf(requestDict);
//                    File x = new File(String.valueOf(requestDict));
                byte[] byteBitmapDecoded = requestDict.toString().getBytes(); /* Here my apps force stop cause OOM */
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And the log is:

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 301989896 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 283MB until OOM"

I need a `byte[]` from this JSONObject but I can't build the JSONObject itself.

Comment: Do not base64 encode images that you want to send to a server. Do not use json to send images to a server.

Comment: @greenapps but my service is use by iOS too. Is there any way with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` and  `android:largeHeap="true"` to your manifest. Since OOM is the most common error occurred while dealing with bitmaps.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And try this code, Which will convert JSONObject to byteArray.

```
  byte[] byteBitmapDecoded = Base64.decode(requestDict.toString, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I tried this before and now I try it again but I still cannot put the String into JSONObject.

Comment: Try this code to get the JSON object that you mentioned. `try {
            JSONObject image = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            image.put("image","encodedImageBase64");
            result.put("result",image);
            Log.d("TAG", "Result: "+result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("TAG","JSONException: "+e);
        }`

Comment: hi @Archana , sorry for slow response, `largeHeap = "true" ` in manifest its work but only in some device.

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta The above code will give you the required format  of JSON and I don't know why do you want to convert an entire JSON object to bytes.

Comment: because I need to use the bytes for post method body on `Volley`. OOM still occur rarely but if its happen the Apps will crash on user device.

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta Please check for the updated answer. I hope it might help you.